# How to get contact that is deleted or updated from device contact list in android

Tags: android

I want to get contact that is either deleted or updated from device contact list.I have used content observer but not getting any details of contact that is being updated or deleted.

So is there any listener for that so we can get contact that is being deleted or updated in device contact list or any action fired from system while deleted or updated contact.

**Update**:
What actually my application requirment is:

if user delete contact or update contact in device contact list like

[image]
 [image]
[image]

and if user delete that contact then my application require that deleted contact info

As you suggest me to use content observer and lookup uri but using this i am only know that contact is delete but not get any information regarding that delete contact.

So is there any way to get delete contact information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey vijay how did you solve this problem.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `ContentObserver`, it is what you are looking for, You can check this thread for further usage of [`ContentObserver`](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/any-listener-for-added-updated-and-deleted-contacts-t15230.html)

Further link for an example of `ContentObserver`,
[`Observing content`](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2008/03/observing-content.html)

**UPDATE:**

[`Loookup URI`](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) - If your application needs to maintain references to contacts, you should use lookup keys instead of the traditional row ids. You can acquire a lookup key from the contact itself, it is a column on the `ContactsContract.Contacts` table.

You can register `ContentObserver` for a particular `Uri` that you are interested in using `Loookup URI`

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.
                                                   CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,lookupKey);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(lookupUri, false, myObserver);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but i have used Content Observer not usefully for me because i want the details of contact that is either updated or deleted and that is what content observer not give me.

Comment: What you had used? what problem you are facing in that?

Comment: i have used ContentObserver.Then when we add contact in contact list of device then onchage method of ContentObserver is called but this method does not give details of that contact.so where i am getting this details of added contact .Aslo required for delete and edit contact.This is my problem getting or not.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope you are looking for LookUp Uri concept.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but what my application requirement is show in update question.so is there any solution for that if yes then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

First u need to register this receiver in your main activity--

```
 getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,new MyCOntentObserver());
```

### after that

```
public class MyCOntentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MyCOntentObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d("onChange1", "~~~~~~" + selfChange);

        //getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendContactService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        Log.d("deliverSelfNotifications", "~~~~~~fg");
        return true;
    }
}
```